# AngularJS ng-repeat with filter - notarray error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a list of items that I'm displaying with `ng-repeat`.  I want to add a filter to show/hide archived items.

I have added a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="queryFilter.archived">Show archived messages
```

In my controller I have this:

```
$scope.queryFilter = {
    archived: false
};
```

My list of items is displayed in a table.  I've tried the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="message in messages | filter : queryFilter">

<tr ng-repeat="message in messages | filter : { archived: queryFilter.archived }">

<tr ng-repeat="message in messages | filter : queryFilter track by $index">
```

I get this error:

> Error: [filter:notarray]
>
> Expected array but received: {}

**The filtering does work** but I want to know why I am getting the error.

Comment: What is your massage structure? this "archive: true/false" doesn't mean anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `messages` must be containing the data in `Object` form not in the `Array` form.

That is why this error is being thrown. Check the doc https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray

From the docs:

> Filter must be used with an array so a subset of items can be
>   returned. The array can be initialized asynchronously and therefore
>   null or undefined won't throw this error.

So make sure, your `$scope.messages` containing data in array form not in the Object form.

Answer (score 7):

I had initialised `messages` as an object.

Changing `$scope.messages = {};` to `$scope.messages = [];` made the error go away.

Comment: Very cool! Of all the options I tried, just this small tweak made those errors go away. I'd even gone to the length of using a custom function to map the object into an array, but then my object had nested objects and things started getting out of hands.

Answer (score 5):

The track by $ index makes angular syntax incorrect, since it is directly positioned behind the filter instruction. Try moving it **behind** the repeat statement so there is a clear separation between the track by and filter statements.

```
<tr ng-repeat="message in messages | filter : queryFilter track by $index">
```

Answer (score 4):

queryfilter is an object not an array. So apply the ng-repeat on queryfilter as given below
`<tr ng-repeat = "message in messages | filter : queryFilter track by $index">`

if queryfilter is array then simply use

`<tr ng-repeat = "message in messages | filter : queryFilter">`

**track by $index is necessary whenever we loop the object**

Comment: The thing that has messed me up every time trying to filter, is that the filter needs to go BEFORE the `track by`, otherwise the filter gets applied to the `$index` variable, which results in the "not an array" error. Had to dig into the angular code to see what was going on. Hope this helps someone else from tearing their hair out...